# Can't read CoffeeScript global variable

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have two coffeescript files, the first have these lines:

```
jQuery(document).ready ($) ->
   dispatcher.bind "createuserchannel", (channelid) ->
     root = (exports ? this)
     root.channel_user = dispatcher.subscribe(channelid)
```

and the latter these:

```
jQuery(document).ready ($) ->
 root = (exports ? this)
 console.log root.channel_user
```

I don't know why but in the Chrome console when i write `Object.keys(window)` the `channel_user` appears as a global variable but if i try to access it from Javascript only gets Undefined

Comment: Well, how are you trying to access it from JavaScript?

Comment: @minitech In the console with "window.channel_user" and in my code with "root.user_channel"

Comment: Yeah, that’s because `user_channel` and `channel_user` are not the same

Comment: @minitech sorry, the hurry, i've corrected.

Comment: What’s `dispatcher`? Are you sure that `this` is the global object inside its callback?

Comment: @minitech It's a Websocket function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

The `dispatcher.bind` is an asynchronous function so at the time I access the variable from this function:

```
jQuery(document).ready ($) ->
 root = (exports ? this)
 console.log root.channel_user
```

channel_user is still not assigned.
To solve the problem i've added this line:

```
jQuery(document).ready ($) ->
     dispatcher.bind "createuserchannel", () ->
      root = (exports ? this)
      console.log root.channel_user
```

In this way `root.channel_user` will be called only when `channel_user` has been setted.

Answer (score 1):

Inside callbacks to jQuery events (such as your second case), jQuery sets `this` to the object that fired the event (in this case, `document`).  You have two options that I see:

First, you could explicitly use `window`.  Its not clear whether this would fit your use-case.

```
root = (exports ? window)
```

Second, you could use the CoffeeScript fat arrow to retain the `this` from the outer scope.  Note that if you're depending on the other `this` behavior anywhere else in that function, this will cause trouble.

```
jQuery(document).ready ($) =>
```

I would assume the same is going on in your second case, but without knowing exactly what `dispatcher` is, its impossible to know for sure.

Comment: Ty for the answer, I've tried with your solutions but didn't work, I don't know why but everything i try to assign as a globar variable inside the dispatcher function give me the same issue.

Comment: @CrazyBarney Maybe the problem is where you're accessing the variables?  I assume this is in a browser (not `node.js`), right?  That would require a slightly different solution.